# Programmatic Move Animation in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I am working to create a Move Animation in windows. I want to move and object from one location to the other. Basically what I am trying to do is to FLIP the selected rectangle and then randomly swap the positions of two Rectangle objects the movement should be shown as an animation.

I have tried and achieved FLIP animation. But now if there are 4 rectangles in a grid, random two rectangles should exchange their positions followed by a move animation. I tried to use the below code. But it is not working.

It just creates a Rectangle in the center of the screen and nothing else.

1) Created a new project

2) Added the below code to the MainPage.xaml.cs file.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Create_And_Run_Animation;
        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }
    private void Create_And_Run_Animation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a red rectangle that will be the target
        // of the animation.
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.Width = 200;
        myRectangle.Height = 200;
        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        myBrush.Color = myColor;
        myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;

        // Add the rectangle to the tree.
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(myRectangle);

        // Create a duration of 2 seconds.
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

        myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
        myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = duration;

        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, myRectangle);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, myRectangle);

        // Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
        // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));

        myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;
        myDoubleAnimation2.To = 200;

        // Make the Storyboard a resource.
        ContentPanel.Resources.Add("unique_id", sb);

        // Begin the animation.
        sb.Begin();
    }
}
```

I haven't added anything in the xaml file. that is just as it is. Is there anything that i need to add to the xaml file for the animation to run properly. ?

Please Help

Comment: Can any one please update on this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never ;-).

Just got the problem myself, you need to add

```
myDoubleAnimation1.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
myDoubleAnimation2.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
```

to your code to force WinRT to do execute animation - otherwise it deems your animation to be not worthy due to possible performance issues ... sigh.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.enabledependentanimation.aspx